# Unhandled Promise Rejection: Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, fetch-api

I am trying to call an API and get back data; defined by my form and appended `onclick` to my API. I've only been doing this for a short time so any help would be appreciated. My main issues (I think) are how to correctly add to an API call, how to get my form from the form to the API request, and how to get that to refill my state. I have looked at several other similar posts about this but they just make me more confused because they are using different methods of calling and API or something else that just leaves me with more questions than when I started. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCocktail } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { INGREDIENT_SEARCH_API_URL } from '../../config';

class Nav extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            drinks: [], //is this the right field from the api?
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET', 
        }

        fetch(INGREDIENT_SEARCH_API_URL + this.state, requestOptions)
        // what gets appended to the api?
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    console.log('Blame it on the rain');
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(responseData => {
                this.setState({ drinks: responseData });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Nav">
                <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCocktail} /> Mix It Up!
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Form inline>
                            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                            <Button type="submit" onClick={() => this.getdrinks()} variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                            {/* What goes into the onClick function? */}
                        </Form>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <div className="NavContent">
                    {this.state.drinks.map(drink => ( drink ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you appending `this.state` to the URL?

Comment: idk... the example I have uses... this.props.match.params.{/*component*/}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured out. Thank you for the help along the way.

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.searchValue = '';

    this.state = {
      drinks: []
    }
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    console.log('change', this.searchValue);
    this.searchValue = this.textInput.current.value;
  }

  handleSearchClick = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET"
    };

    fetch(INGREDIENT_SEARCH_API_URL + this.searchValue, requestOptions)
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          console.log('error');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.drinks);
        this.setState({ drinks: response.drinks });
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
  }

  gotoDrink = (id) => {
    this.props.history.push('/d/' + id)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCocktail} /> Mix It Up!</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Form inline>
              <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" ref={this.textInput} onChange={() => this.handleChange()} />
              <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => this.handleSearchClick()}>Search</Button>
            </Form>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        <div className="Content">
          <Route
            path="/" exact
            render={() => (
              <div className="LeftContent">
                {this.state.drinks.map(drink => (
                  <div className="DrinkName" onClick={() => this.gotoDrink(drink.idDrink)}>
                    {drink.strDrink}
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/d/:id"
            render={(props) => <DrinkComponent {...props} />}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `.catch()` to handle Promise rejections. Essentially it is just fall-back logic that executes when your API request fails.

Additionally, your API request looks incorrect. You shouldn't have to put your `state` object in the path. I'm assuming what you actually want is to add a single string from you drinks array.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET', 
    }

    fetch(INGREDIENT_SEARCH_API_URL + "/" + this.state.drinks[0], requestOptions)
    // what gets appended to the api?
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                console.log('Blame it on the rain');
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(responseData => {
            this.setState({ drinks: responseData });
        })
        .catch((errors) => {
            console.log(errors)
        })
}
```

Comment: yes; I want to add whatever drink is submitted in the form

Comment: Right, so you wouldn't want to pass in an object  {}  to the URL path. Do you know if the API actually wants an object after the backslash? Seems like they would want a string @JasonCalk

Answer (score 0):

why are u appending this.state with Api endpoint url. The first argument of fetch is endpoint url and it must be a string . fetch(url,{options}).
if you want to pass queries on url use a '?'

```
    const data=["aa","bb","cc"]
    const stringData=data.join()
    const params='?'+stringdata
    fetch(INGREDIENT_SEARCH_API_URL+params, requestOptions)
                .then(responseData => {
                    this.setState({ drinks: responseData });
                })
                .catch(res => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        console.log('Blame it on the rain');
                    }
                })
```